# Python Ranking Program Using Numbers

Tags: python

The promoter wants to be able to classify donors based on how much they have contributed to the overall goal of the campaign.

Write a function easy_donor_rank(percent_donated) that takes a number indicating percent donated and returns a string containing the rank attained by giving such a donation.

For example, the function call easy_donor_rank(1.0) should return the string 'Bronze'.

See the table below to see the list of donor ranks.

Donor Classification

- Donation Percentage Donor Rank
- 0% or less
- Error Less than 2%   Bronze
- 2% to 15% inclusive  Silver more than 15%    Gold

The code I have right now works but I always get a "None" in the end of every output

```
def easy_donor_rank(percent_donated):

    if percent_donated <= 0:
        print("Error")

    if percent_donated < 2:
        print("Bronze")

    elif percent_donated >= 2 and percent_donated <= 15:
        print("Silver")

    else:
        print("Gold")
```

Comment: "_I always get a "None" in the end of every output_" : I think it's because you just `print` the result instead of actually `return`ing it, as stated in the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your code works for me. I made a small modification only for your `if` condition. I change the second `if` to `elif`.

```
def easy_donor_rank(percent_donated):
    if percent_donated <= 0:
        print("Error")
    elif percent_donated < 2:
        print("Bronze")
    elif percent_donated <= 15:
        print("Silver")
    else:
        print("Gold")
```

Answer (score 0):

it's work in python 3.6

```
def easy_donor_rank(percent_donated):
    if percent_donated <= 0:
        return "Error"
    elif percent_donated < 2:
        return ("Bronze")

    elif percent_donated >= 2 and percent_donated <= 15:
        return ("Silver")
    else:
        return ("Gold")
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code I have right now works but I always get a "None" in the end
>   of every output.

I'm going to assume that you are trying to `print` the return of `easy_donor_rank`.

```
$ cat test.py
def easy_donor_rank(percent_donated):    
    if percent_donated <= 0:
        print("Error")
    if percent_donated < 2:
        print("Bronze")
    elif percent_donated >= 2 and percent_donated <= 15:
        print("Silver")
    else:
        print("Gold")

print(easy_donor_rank(1.2))
```

But because you don't `return` anything, it will return `None`, so `None` gets printed.

```
$ python3 test.py
Bronze
None
```

You just need to `return` the result instead of `print`ing it inside the function.
See [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7129285/2745495)

```
$ cat test.py
def easy_donor_rank(percent_donated):
    if percent_donated <= 0:
        return "Error"
    if percent_donated < 2:
        return "Bronze"
    elif percent_donated >= 2 and percent_donated <= 15:
        return ("Silver")
    else:
        return "Gold"

print(easy_donor_rank(1.2))

$ python3 test.py
Bronze
```